# Pass global variable to on event callback function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, eventemitter

In the following code, I'm trying to get `mydata` passed to the callback. This is a sample problem from a bigger problem I'm having. I'm assuming this is a scope issue. What is wrong with my code and/or what should I do?

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var myevent      = new EventEmitter();
var mydata       = 'my data!';

function myfunc (data, mydata) {
  console.log(data);
  console.log(mydata);
};

myevent.on('data', function(data, mydata) {myfunc(data,mydata)});

myevent.emit('data', "data!");
```

returns:

```
data!
undefined
```

I'd like it to return:

```
data!
my data!
```

Comment: you should avoid naming local and global variables the same name as they will shadow each other and cause confusion.

Comment: If the variable is global (or if `myfunc` can access it via closure), why do you care to "pass" it?

Comment: @bfavaretto I was trying to simulate a bigger issue I was having that I thought was a different scope issue with event-stream and socket.io. I've learned that my event-stream.pipepline.emit should emit the socket.io socket so I can do socket.emit(data), which is a different question entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'm going to make a wild guess (since i am not familiar with `EventEmitter`) and say that `emit`'s first parameter is the name of the event, and the remaining parameters are passed to the handler.

if that is the case, you're not passing anything to the second callback parameter, which is why it comes in as `undefined`. try this instead:

```
myevent.emit('data', "data!", "mydata!");
```

note: i am ignoring your shadowing issue as it is not related to the problem, just a bad practice.

Comment: You're right. I drew up this simple example(with bad choice if naming) from a problem I'm wanting to use socket.io to emit data whenever my event-stream emits data, emitting that same data.

Answer (score 5):

The parameter `mydata` in the callback's parameter list is hiding the global variable of the same name.

As you passed no parameter in that position, its value is `undefined`.

Either:

1. change the name of the parameter, or
2. remove the parameter, or
3. pass the required value, e.g. `myevent.emit('data', "data!", mydata);`

p.s:

```
myevent.on('data', function(data, mydata) {myfunc(data,mydata)});
```

would be better just written as:

```
myevent.on('data', myfunc);
```

Comment: 3. pass the parameter on the emit call

Answer (score 2):

Modified code: You can access a global variable. from anywhere you do not need to pass it as parameter. even you pass a parameter. you can access a global variable using `window.mydata`  since you are using nodejs you can access a global variable using `global.mydata`

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var myevent      = new EventEmitter();
var mydata       = 'my data!';

function myfunc (data) {
  console.log(data);
  console.log(mydata);
};

myevent.on('data', myfunc);

myevent.emit('data', "data!");
```